# PHP IF with multiple days of the week

Tags: php, date

Is this possible?

```
$d=date("D");
...
else if ($d=='(Thu|Fri|Sat)') {
```

I can get a single day of the week working.

```
if ($d=='Wed') {
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use an or, or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the OR operator:

```
else if ($d=='Thu' || $d=='Fri' || $d=='Sat') {
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if (in_array($d, array("Thu", "Fri", "Sat"))) {

}
```

Comment: I would prefer a `switch` in this case since you get more control.

Comment: @Jon: I'm using in_array() and it's a lot more clean!

Comment: @Martin I know it's clean, but there's a lack of control if the OP wants sub-conditional logic. It could get really messy then.

Comment: @Jon: yeah, but does the job for this case. I just showed what I prefer :)

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use `or` or `||`?

```
else if ($d=='Thu' || $d=='Fri' || $d=='Sat') {
```

---

If you dont want to stick to simplicity then use preg_replace()<sup>***[[docs]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)***</sup>

```
preg_match('^(Thu|Fri|Sat)$', $yourtext, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if(count($matches)) {
    /// found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. For what you want, [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is the best choice.

```
if(in_array($d, array('Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'))
  // do something if any case is true
```

If you want more control, [`switch` and `case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) are very handy and give you more control over different cases.

```
$d = date('D');

switch($d) {
  case 'Thu':
  case 'Fri':
  case 'Sat':
    // do something for Thu, Fri, or Sat
    break;

  case 'Mon':
    // do something only for Mon
  case 'Tue':
    // do something for Mon or Tue.
    break;
}
```

The first set of cases will apply the following code (up until `break`) if any or all of the conditions are met.

The second set will apply the code between cases `Mon` and `Tue` if `Mon` is true, and then continue to `Tue` if it is true.

`switch` and `case` can be very useful, especially here if you want real control.

Answer (score 2):

`$d == '(Thu|Fri|Sat)'` will only match if `$d` matches that exact string.

You could:

- Use a [regular expression](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php): `preg_match('/^(Thu|Fri|Sat)$/', $d)`,
- An [array of values](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php): `in_array($d, array( 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ))`, or
- Mulitple if statements: `if($d == 'Thu' || $d == 'Fri' || $d == 'Sat');`
- Use a [switch/case](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) structure

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(in_array($d, array('Thu', 'Fri', 'etc'))){
}
```

Or with ||

```
if($d == 'Thu' || $d == 'Fri' || etc)
```